# Computing Welford's variance for multiple data.table columns using RStorm

Tags: r, statistics, data.table, grouping, lapply

Given the following `data.table` `dt`:

```
    i a  b
 1: 1 1 NA
 2: 2 1 NA
 3: 2 2  2
 4: 3 1  1
 5: 3 2  2
 6: 3 3 NA
 7: 4 1 NA
 8: 4 2  2
 9: 4 3  3
10: 4 4 NA
```

I want to calculate a running variance on columns `a` and `b` grouped by column `i` using [Welford's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) and the `RStorm` package facilities. I followed along the example on [page 4 of RStorm's vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RStorm/RStorm.pdf) and read through an [introductory paper on RStorm](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2014-1/kaptein.pdf), but I'm unable to figure out how to make it work. Here's my code:

```
library(RStorm)
dt = data.table(i=c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4), a=c(1,1:2,1:3,1:4), b=c(NA,NA,2,1,2,NA,NA,2,3,NA)
in_cols = c('a','b')
out_cols <- paste0(in_cols, '.var.Welford')
## Calculaing variance using Welford's method
## See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance
## See: "RStorm: Developing and Testing Streaming Algorithms in R", R Journal Vol 6/1
var.Welford <- function(x, ...) {
    x <- as.numeric(x[1])
    params <- GetHash("params2")
    if (!is.data.frame(params)) {
        params <- list()
        params$M <- params$S <- params$n <- 0
    }
    x <- ifelse(is.na(x), params$M, x)
    n <- params$n + 1
    delta <- (x - params$M)
    M <- params$M + ( delta / (n + 1) )
    S <- params$S + delta*(x - M)
    SetHash("params2", data.frame(n=n,M=M,S=S))
    var <- ifelse(n > 1, S / (n-1), 0)
    TrackRow("var.Welford", data.frame(var = var))
}
computeVarWelford <- function(x) {
    topology <- Topology(as.data.frame(x=as.data.frame(x)))
    topology <- AddBolt(topology, Bolt(var.Welford, listen = 0))
    result <- RStorm(topology)
    # GetTrack('var.Welford', result)
    result$track$var.Welford
}

## Execute:
dt[, eval(out_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {return(as.list(computeVarWelford(x))[1])})
, by=i, .SDcols = in_cols]
```

Executing the line above transforms `dt` into:

```
    i a  b                       a.var.Welford                       b.var.Welford
 1: 1 1 NA                                   0                                   0
 2: 2 1 NA                                 0,2                   0.000000,2.666667
 3: 2 2  2                                 0,2                   0.000000,2.666667
 4: 3 1  1                         0.0,2.0,2.5                               0,2,1
 5: 3 2  2                         0.0,2.0,2.5                               0,2,1
 6: 3 3 NA                         0.0,2.0,2.5                               0,2,1
 7: 4 1 NA 0.000000,2.000000,2.500000,3.333333 0.000000,2.666667,3.375000,2.250000
 8: 4 2  2 0.000000,2.000000,2.500000,3.333333 0.000000,2.666667,3.375000,2.250000
 9: 4 3  3 0.000000,2.000000,2.500000,3.333333 0.000000,2.666667,3.375000,2.250000
10: 4 4 NA 0.000000,2.000000,2.500000,3.333333 0.000000,2.666667,3.375000,2.250000
```

It's pretty clear from the results that the entire list of variances for each (column,group) pair is being copied into **each element** of that (column,group) pair, instead of being mapped to **all elements** of that (column,group) pair. This is what I really want:

```
    i a  b     a.var.Welford        b.var.Welford
 1: 1 1 NA     0                    0
 2: 2 1 NA     0                    0
 3: 2 2  2     2                    2.666667
 4: 3 1  1     0.0                  0
 5: 3 2  2     2.0                  2
 6: 3 3 NA     2.5                  1
 7: 4 1 NA     0.000000             0.000000
 8: 4 2  2     2.000000             2.666667
 9: 4 3  3     2.500000             3.375000
10: 4 4 NA     3.333333             2.250000
```

I'm really hoping there is a simple fix for this, but I haven't been able to figure it out for the life of me. Every time I try what I think should work, I end up getting an error from `data.table` saying

> All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. If you are
>   trying something like j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then use := by
>   group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge afterwards.

which I understand to mean that the dimensions of the return value of whatever `FUN` I try in my `lapply(.SD, FUN)` code doesn't correspond to the dimensions the `data.table` expects for a column for that group.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

**EDIT : Okay the solution was very simple. I feel stupid. But here's the answer for who may need it later**

```
## Make sure to use [[]] at the end. My problem came entirely down to using [].
dt[, eval(out_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {return(as.list(computeVarWelford(x))[[1]])})
   , by=i, .SDcols = in_cols]
```

This works like a charm. I got what I needed:

```
    i a  b a.var.Welford b.var.Welford
 1: 1 1 NA      0.000000      0.000000
 2: 2 1 NA      0.000000      0.000000
 3: 2 2  2      2.000000      2.666667
 4: 3 1  1      0.000000      0.000000
 5: 3 2  2      2.000000      2.000000
 6: 3 3 NA      2.500000      1.000000
 7: 4 1 NA      0.000000      0.000000
 8: 4 2  2      2.000000      2.666667
 9: 4 3  3      2.500000      3.375000
10: 4 4 NA      3.333333      2.250000
```

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar : That will give me k^2 rows for each group with k rows originally. `cSplit` will split each row. I need to split just the first row from each group, but then also place the split values into remaining rows of that group.

Comment: or you could use `rbindlist` like this `rbindlist(lapply(split(data, data$i), function(x){cSplit(x[1,], c('a.var.Welford', 'b.var.Welford'), ',', 'long')}))`

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar Yes, it's a `0`. I fixed the typo. Both your code statements above work....almost. I added the results as an edit in my question above. How can I get rid of the weird parsing/eval errors?

Comment: I do not get what you showed there but you can get rid of that by using `listCol_l(output, c('a.var.Welford', 'b.var.Welford'))`, where output would be the result of above command check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551036/unlisting-columns-by-groups/31551332#31551332) for more

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar Thanks for your effort. I was able to fix my problem upstream, so I no longer need to parse those weird list results per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: I no longer need the hack solution below. Here's the code to solve this problem (note the [[]] instead of [] fix):**

```
dt[, eval(out_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {return(as.list(computeVarWelford(x))[[1]])})
   , by=i, .SDcols = in_cols]
```

---

OLD: Okay, so I figured out a way to make it work finally. But I find the way pretty ugly. I'm going to accept this as my answer for now, but please if anybody has a better solution, I would love to hear it and will accept it as the answer to this question if it's better than mine.

Solution:

```
out_cols_fixed <- paste0(out_cols, '.fixed')
dt[,eval(out_cols_fixed) := lapply(.SD, function(x) { return(x[1][[1]]) }), by=i, .SDcols = out_cols]
dt[,eval(out_cols) := NULL]
setnames(dt, old = out_cols_fixed, new = out_cols)
```

Result for `dt` as desired:

```
    i a  b a.var.Welford b.var.Welford
 1: 1 1 NA      0.000000      0.000000
 2: 2 1 NA      0.000000      0.000000
 3: 2 2  2      2.000000      2.666667
 4: 3 1  1      0.000000      0.000000
 5: 3 2  2      2.000000      2.000000
 6: 3 3 NA      2.500000      1.000000
 7: 4 1 NA      0.000000      0.000000
 8: 4 2  2      2.000000      2.666667
 9: 4 3  3      2.500000      3.375000
10: 4 4 NA      3.333333      2.250000
```

I tried the following first, but it didn't work. Can anyone explain why?

```
dt[,eval(out_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) { return(x[1][[1]]) }), by=i, .SDcols = out_cols]
```

I get the following error from running the line above:

> Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(eval(out_cols), lapply(.SD,
>   function(x) { :    Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('list'). To
>   check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest
>   cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS
>   of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)